# Blazor WebAssembly treats css differently

Tags: css, blazor, webassembly

In my MainLayout.razor I have the following:

```
<NavLink href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
   <span class="bdx-link" style="margin-left: 1.5em;"></span>Home
   </NavLink>

   <NavLink href="EntryGate">
   <span class="bdx-link" style="margin-left: 1.5em;"></span>Login
   </NavLink>

   <NavLink href="chat">
   <span class="bdx-link" style="margin-left: 1.5em;"></span>Chat
   </NavLink>

   <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" class="bdx-link" target="_blank" style="margin-left: 
        1.5em;margin-right:1.5em">About</a>
</NavLink>
```

In site.css I have the following:

```
.bdx-link {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #0A98DB
}

.bdx-link a:hover {
    color: aqua;
}
```

The About item displays properly.  The NavLink items don't get the proper font or color.  Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Your `<span></span>` tags are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard.  For NavLink the class statement must go in the NavLink line, not the span line.

Comment: And add ```;``` after ```color: #0A98DB```